# Error message on Main Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner in Android Studio. I am using Windows. I am getting error on my     main activity. error: illegal start of expression in android.Please help me to fix this problem.Thanks in advance.

The Code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button Expense=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Expense);
        Button Income=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Income);

        Expense.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Addpanel.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        Income.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Addincome.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

            }

        });

        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
            DatabaseHelper myDb;
            EditText editproduct,editamount;
            Button btnsave;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_addpanel);
                myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                editproduct = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.product);
                editamount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
                btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
                save();
            }
            public  void save() {
                btnsave.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editproduct.getText().toString(),
                                        editamount.getText().toString()
                                );
                                if(isInserted == true)
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                else
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data not     Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
            public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle(title);
                builder.setMessage(Message);
                builder.show();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why there are two MainActivity?

Comment: Your class contains two `MainActivity` and two `OnCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

you have created two MainActivity in your code so you get error of illegal start of expression. You have to write your code in single class Mainactivity.

Comment: I am beginner. My project is to create a expense app with simple design add product description and amount and then save the details to database. How can i implement this .Thanks for your comment

Comment: You can use api call using PHP or any other api or use sqlite database to store your record.

Answer (score 1):

You have two MainActivity, that could be causing the error. Try getting rid of the one of them.

Answer (score 1):

there are two activity in one class you need to create two seprated class for both MainActivity.

Comment: I am beginner. My project is to create a expense app with simple design add product description and amount and then save the details to database. How can i implement this .Thanks for your comment –